# A question about polymorphing yourself

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph

If you polymorph yourself into a chair do you instantly break concentration and turn back to normal?

Comment: I've rolled this back to its original version. The edit changing the question to *true polymorph* invalidated the correct given answer and did not match the dupe target.

Answer (score 3):

Polymorph has to be a beast, so you can't turn into a chair with that spell:

> the new form can be any beast (PHB 266)