# If I am concentrating on Spirit Guardians when I am True Polymorphed into a copper piece, can I continue to concentrate to maintain the spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, polymorph, concentration, objects

When you become an object, do you keep the ability to concentrate on spells?

Comment: Highly related at least: [Does whether a Wizard can maintain the spell Polymorph upon themselves depend on the form they change into?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59071/52137)

Comment: @Someone_Evil The only reason I don't think that's relevant is because the logic seems to focus on being turned into a creature (*à la Polymorph*, not *True Polymorph*). In the other answer which mention a Jeremy Crawford ruling, it very much sounds like he was only considering the possibility of turning into another creature.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Was jumping from this question: [A question about true polymorphing yourself](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/82397/52137), but this is maybe more relevant: [Can you True Polymorph yourself into an object?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/144222/52137)

Comment: @Someone_Evil In this case, it isn't a question about True Polymorph's duration because I'm not the caster; I'm the victim of it. What they've said about concentrating being associated with memory seems dubious, but is more related. Just wasn't sure if there was an official ruling one way or the other.

Comment: Is this how sentient items come to be?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### You lose concentration on a spell if you are incapacitated.

There is nothing that explicitly says you are incapacitated while you are an object, but it is quite clear that you are.

The [incapacitated condition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Incapacitated) says:

> An incapacitated creature can't take actions or reactions.

Notably, a creature that is *only* incapacitated can still use its movement. A penny is... just a penny - that cannot take actions or reactions. The [*Dungeon Master's Guide* defines an object](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#Objects) as:

> a discrete, inanimate item.

You are incapacitated, nay, worse than incapacitated - inanimate. And the [rules for concentration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Concentration) say:

> You lose concentration on a spell if you are incapacitated

To be clear, this is not RAW in the most strict sense, hence my opening statement: *there is nothing that explicitly says you are incapacitated while you are an object*.

Comment: I like this answer a lot better than the memory argument that's been shown a couple of times already. A very clear argument for being incapacitated by definition (even though it applies to creatures not objects, it is de facto incapacitation) plus the ruling that incapacitation drops concentration.

Comment: This might be sophistry, but this feels like the all humans are socrates problem... the incapacitated condition does not state that any creature that can't take actions or reactions is incapacitated, and so I'm not convinced that RAW inanimate implies incapacitated based on what you cited.

Comment: I added a note at the end. Yes, to claim this is a strictly RAW ruling is [*affirming the consequent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent).

Comment: I would vote that this is actually pretty RAW as well because an object, being inanimate is incapacitated in all sense of the terminology.